# ACE.OleDB connection for AccessDB on MacOS

Tags: c#, macos, ms-access, asp.net-web-api

We have an WebApi application that runs properly on Windows but not on MacOS. Apparently there are problems directly related to our MS Access database.

Is there any Access Database Engine assembly for MacOS (because that's what we're missing)? Or should we drop Access in favour of sqlite (I guess sqlite works for .NET on MacOS)?

This is the current provider we use for access: `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0`

Kind regards!

Answer (score 1):

There isn't. Depending on your application, however, you could use [UCanAccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html), a JDBC Access driver (possibly with a JDBC-to-ODBC bridge), [Jackcess](http://jackcess.sourceforge.net), a Java library for working with Access databases, or a commercial ODBC Access driver. Note that some drivers, like mdbtools or the one by [Actual](http://www.actualtech.com/product_access.php) provide read-only access.